# How do I type-narrow a function's response when given a generic type or argument in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

If I have something like this:

```
import 'isomorphic-fetch';

enum Format {
    kml = 'kml',
    geojson = 'geojson'
}
interface Kml {
    kml: {
        header: string;
        document: string;
    }
}
interface Geojson {
    features: [
        {
            properties: {}
        }
    ]
};
type FormatTypes = Kml | Geojson;

async function formatResponse(formatToUse: Format.kml, input:Response): Promise<Kml>;
async function formatResponse(formatToUse: Format.geojson, input:Response): Promise<Geojson>;
async function formatResponse(formatToUse: Format, input: Response) {
    switch(formatToUse) {
        case Format.kml: {
            return {
                kml: {
                    header: 'blah',
                    document: '<document></document>'
                }
            };
        }
        case Format.geojson: {
            return { features: [{ properties: {} }] };
        }
        default: {
            return assertUnreachable(formatToUse);
        }
    }
}

async function fetchAndFormat(format: Format) {
    const response = await fetch(`https://example.com`);
    return await formatResponse(format, response);
}

async function fetchAndFormatRetryingOnFail(format: Format) {
    let numberOfRetries = 3;
    while (true) {
        try {
            return await fetchAndFormat(format);
        } catch (error) {
            numberOfRetries--;
            if (numberOfRetries === 0) {
                throw error;
            }
        }
    }
}

function mergeDatasets<T extends FormatTypes>(format: Format, datasetOne: T, datasetTwo: T): T {
    switch (format) {
        case Format.kml: {
            return datasetTwo;
        }
        case Format.geojson: {
            return datasetOne;
        }
        default: {
            assertUnreachable(format);
        }
    }
}

const assertUnreachable = (x: never, customErrorMessage: string = `Unreachable code reached, handling for value '${x}' is not defined.`): never => {
    throw new Error(customErrorMessage);
};
```

How do I best type formatResponse and mergeDatasets to state that it will return the `Kml` type, or the `Geojson` type based on either the formatToUse argument or a generic?
That is, I'd like to do something like:

```
const data = fetchAndFormatRetryingOnFail<Format.kml>(Format.kml);
// or
const data = fetchAndFormatRetryingOnFail(Format.kml);
// I now have compile-time typesafety that f is a Kml type
```

In particular, I'd like to use it like this:

```
const exampleUsage = async () => {
    // should be valid
    let datasetOne = await fetchAndFormatRetryingOnFail(Format.kml);
    let datasetTwo = await fetchAndFormatRetryingOnFail(Format.kml);
    let mergedData = mergeDatasets(Format.kml, datasetOne, datasetTwo);
    // should explode
    // datasetOne = await fetchAndFormatRetryingOnFail(Format.kml);
    // datasetTwo = await fetchAndFormatRetryingOnFail(Format.geojson);
    // mergedData = mergeDatasets(Format.kml, datasetOne, datasetTwo);

    // would be nice if I could do this (not sure how to write the switch statement though)
    // datasetOne = await fetchAndFormatRetryingOnFail(Format.kml);
    // datasetTwo = await fetchAndFormatRetryingOnFail(Format.kml);
    // mergedData = mergeDatasets(datasetOne, datasetTwo);
    // if this still exploded at compile time
    // datasetOne = await fetchAndFormatRetryingOnFail(Format.kml);
    // datasetTwo = await fetchAndFormatRetryingOnFail(Format.geojson);
    // mergedData = mergeDatasets(datasetOne, datasetTwo);
}
```

I've tried using function overloading, but that leads to some frustrating restrictions. For example, the following:

```
async function formatResponse(formatToUse: Format.kml, input:Response): Promise<Kml>;
async function formatResponse(formatToUse: Format.geojson, input:Response): Promise<Geojson>;
async function formatResponse(formatToUse: Format, input: Response) {
    // ...snip
}
```

Means that this:

```
const fetchAndFormat = async (format: format) => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://example.com`);
    return await formatResponse(format, response);
}
```

Gives an error like this:

> No overload matches this call.
>
> Overload 1 of 2, '(formatToUse: Format.kml, input: Response): Promise', gave the following error.
>
> Argument of type 'Format' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Format.kml'.
>
> Overload 2 of 2, '(formatToUse: Format.geojson, input: Response): Promise', gave the following error.
>
> Argument of type 'Format' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Format.geojson'.

I can solve this by moving the overloading up to here:

```
async function fetchAndFormatRetryingOnFail(formatToUse: Format.kml): Promise<Kml>;
async function fetchAndFormatRetryingOnFail(formatToUse: Format.geojson): Promise<Geojson>;
async function fetchAndFormatRetryingOnFail(format: Format) {
    // ...snip
}
```

However this feels weird because I'm moving it away from the implementation just to make the compiler happier. It doesn't feel like it's part of `fetchAndFormatRetryingOnFail` contract to specify the type narrowing and it feels like mistakes could slip in via this.

I've got a [Playground example here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=103&ssc=2&pln=85&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAcmAZwiaYAWwDGBaAMwFMYdMEBuAWAChaiA7AVxDgDFoQBDeAb1riC4AaxAAbOAF5EosQgA0AoQHMiEAFaoGUxKo1aEtAL61gDGESgEuOInADS4uPxoBIWQC5ntV68xEuABNLL2QYKDNlajdXQIgcFkYYUPDI6NcTGkyzCysbOwBxNU0IbRdXYh4mKCJkLwBtH1dy3zAoCDBLGGBar15M3wGAXWNomABPTvZOHgAVSdqdRwkAHzgi-VLo2gB6HbguZHGGHDgCJhPu0rOZmAAlWsgGZCIACgJb2YgAVRevDig3BgADpZPI4GYwExknAHsgni8AJReAAK7RAKCIAB5lgA+aJ7A5HE5nC44K7aD6AnhwhFvKlAr6-Ij-W7AvQlBjgyHQry00pI1HozFYjac-G0Q7HU7nS7Aa4MmmPAX0z4-P7TakwbkMKEw-nPIiI7w0IRwZAAd2ApEw7zVzONLjNZpwhzsAKBoPEfSarhqMGqZV97m9Jt84f8QRCiAARmIuORFDFw3EEiAkl4EFjU4lzLisTsc+m84ZkxlfUZos6hJlq4JXS9NZ6OVofcn-YHnGcAgGanU4PVeHA2h0uj1+-04EYhlOq3Xa3XgtYmGIYU662aO1BtIcXrBvgwajZMFw46qtUykXPqwvBJlMoSpSTZeT5ZSSGQAIIMQIenh2rVWS1L0xGROA0TQEU8QJfYnxlMkKW7G1v1-W4AKBIDm2KLQwIgjEXlFbDSglGg4NJOUFQ-TAUL-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-dDwCZOzx0V4pK8TmADdLHBBIwjQQvtoAWVqZAuFUFIIlinRBMT3vG76pTgiM48iECcETx-MRIhuKA4BHrgxCGxAABJeCkowEAhVWGAgeAlzMQ-gRU4eiBj0vpIXEYZs4QG+nnOAM9oCvEnjAaeRdoDz2QIvVQLdtg0HbmERWskwDyV+EvOw0gyKvGNCAsMhJkAVyrjXOw18z6BB8HVN2YdOZcS0rNKiNFbhRRinFCqiVXi0V8ukFhodMb8w4TNfi1EFqRVKvw+KlURGyHTq4FhktAjSy4DoSWOjZbCKduIY2mNsamJIPzdRVCaFiGrtJfBEBgg+EJBI-W7CSGcNkTwhR9lyoJXcqo8Q1j9huI9sTaR2luHyKBHw-xKi2TpQYCEiGlhVDaLhnotJUt2aIyCWICxHMiCFKsZg1whJia0NrgwXAdhLpwAAJJrUrnYtGEA4AfRQC40J7NsaRK4cVXhij4lCPySksJUjPEyLmnIiKsThmxWUaM4xoF0iEi0TorJUMcnu0RmE8xrDJHExSfUzpqswiJQkA4sQTjD4HHgEpcAiU7DdHTN0w57jiEHC8TMnx8y-GLMEYElZ4y+YRKmVEwZviyqAoCUY4CSSUkbMydIfRuTXj7M5iU450QjBAA), this is using the raised function overloading.